# Protractor - How to verify that script is loaded and running in the page by expect in Jasmine?

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, automation, jasmine, protractor

How can I perform test to verify some JavaScript (e.g. angular-all.js) is loaded and running in the page?

Is there any option to this by "expect" in Jasmine?

**Something like:**

expect(browser.driver.*script*("angulat-all.js").*IsLoaded()*)).toBe(true), 30000);

Comment: If it is supposed to load with your page it will load. All Protractor does is load your page and then work with it like a user would.

Comment: It is exactly as you typed, except:
`expect(browser.executeScript("JavaScript to check the script is loaded, that returns bool value")).toBeTruthy()`